# Is there something i can install as an electrician that can help flickering led bulbs and a.c. on start up

Tags: electrical

I am an electrician who bought Sylvania led bulbs. They all flicker. I have re-deviced my whole home and checked all connections. Not the issue. Dimmers not the issue. Cheap bulbs maybe.my customers have the same problem. I was researching online about whole home capacitors and I haven't found evidence that this will help. Anyone have ideas suggestions other than replacing all my new crappy led bulbs?

Comment: Maybe AC soft starts.  LEDs do not like power/voltage changes.  I am assuming the flickering only occurs when a high wattage motor comes on and is not constant.

Comment: Can you clarify the conditions where you have flicker - it's not particularly clear from your description. They all flicker all the time? They all flicker, but *only* when an  air conditioning unit is starting?

Comment: I have a good quality but not best quality 3 year old a/c system. The LED lights in the kitchen dim very slightly when the compressor comes on. I do not intend to try a soft start kit. In our 1970 build house with aluminum wiring receptacles and lighting are mixed on the same breakers. When I would switch on our vacuum incandescent lights on the same breaker would dim significntly. &^%*$#@! Eventually I put in two 20 A circuits with #12 copper. I plug the vacuum into one of those new circuits with an extension cord and there is no major dimming of lights in the room I am vacuuming.

Comment: Have you checked your voltage? Is it 120v?

Comment: The only reliable solution for LED flickering I have found is incandescent lights. :)

Answer (score 1):

LEDs differ by method of manufacture. There must be an electronic driver of some kind to turn AC power into the DC that the LEDs require. (which is middle voltage e.g. 40-100 volts DC since many LEDs are in series).

One variety is a "switching power supply" which accepts a variety of input voltage and bucks it down to the LED voltage. These work on 120-240V and ride out minor voltage fluctuations without trouble.

Another variety is much simpler, and simply conditions the 120V  to suit the LED. Fluctuations in 120V voltage cause proportional fluctuations in LED voltage.  "Well that won't be any worse than the same thing with incandescents, right?"  No.  Incandescents respond to the square-cube law - reduce voltage to 95% and power decreases to 95% squared or about 90%.  However, LEDs have a *very, very sharp* voltage/current curve - dropping voltage to 95% may drop current to 75%, giving about 71% net power.

So I think your voltage fluctuations are probably perfectly reasonable and within spec, the LEDs just may be "the sensitive kind".